# How to get count of employeeID attritubute in AD where employeeID = X

Tags: powershell, active-directory, attributes

I'm working on writing a Powershell script that automatically adds new employees on a scheduled task from an automatically generated list that is created nightly. One of the requirements, naturally, is to not create duplicate employees. So, my thought process is to count the number of occurances of an employee ID, and if it is >= "1", then to not create the account and proceed to the next one. When trying to find the count i'm using the following code. However, I'm consistently getting 0 as the return. Can someone correct my query for me. Thanks in advance.

```
$ID = 12345
$COUNT = (Get-ADUser -filter * |where '$_.EmployeeID -eq $ID').count
Write-Output $COUNT
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two things going wrong here. First, when you use `-Filter *`, it gets *all accounts* (up to 1000, unless you use the `ResultPageSize` parameter), loads them all into memory and passes the big list to the `where`. That will take a whole lot longer and more memory than needed, and, if you have more than 1000 accounts in your domain, you won't get accurate results.

Second, [`Get-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser) only returns a specific set of properties, unless you tell it otherwise. Since you didn't tell it that you want `employeeID`, it didn't return it. So `$_.EmployeeID` will always be empty.

Both issues can be solved at the same time by passing your `EmployeeID` filter directly to `Get-ADUser`:

```
$ID = 12345
$COUNT = (Get-ADUser -filter 'EmployeeID -eq $ID').count
Write-Output $COUNT
```

Comment: As an alternative to the Filter-Parameter you can also use LDAPFilter as Parameter (e.g. -LDAPFilter "(EmployeeID=$ID)"), if you like the LDAP-Syntax more.

Comment: Additional Comment: With "-Filter *" you get only all accounts, if they are less than 1000. IF you domains has more users than that you need to use the Parameter ResultPageSize

Comment: @RonnyKaufmann Good point! I updated my answer with that info.